# Initial and final pressures for the Joule-Kelvin expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, cooling

The Joule-Kelvin (or Joule-Thomson) expansion is an isenthalpic expansion in which the reduction of a gas' pressure from $ P_{i} $ to $ P_{f} $ results in a change in Temperature. It results in cooling only if the gas is already below a so-called "Inversion Temperature". Now, it makes sense to me that this inversion temperature is defined at the higher temperature $ P_{i} $, since this is where the cooling process starts. Practically speaking, it also makes sense to me that in order to make a gas liquefier either $ P_{i} $ or $ P_{f} $ would be held at 1 atm. But I also always thought that $ P_{i} $ is usually high pressure gas (higher than 1 atmosphere) whereas $ P_{f} $ would be 1 atm. Or is this just not how it's done? Basically my question comes down to, in practice, is $ P_{i} $ or $ P_{f} $ held at atmospheric pressure, or neither? And if the answer isn't $ P_{i} $ then what pressure is the inversion temperature for gases defined at?

Comment: What's so special about atmospheric pressure?

Comment: It’s the easiest constraint to apply because it’s naturally provided by our atmosphere

Comment: But is actual processing equipment in industry, the downstream pressure is rarely atmospheric pressure.